# Android - Custom cells for tableview in android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I want to implement a table with one column, or maybe a list in Android. 
I would like to customize the cells.
Do you know some tutorial that can help? 
Thanks in advance,
Luda

Comment: Try here!  http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/  Also, do you have a specific coding question, if not, then this really is not a proper question posting!!!

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Post it as an answer so I could accept it

Comment: Thanks for the vote and acceptance :-)  Glad to have helped!

Comment: I didn't voted. Guess it's not just me that likes your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great place to start:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

This is a great tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's an old question but, I can help anyone who has got same request.

There is a [TableView](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView) Library for Android. It's also open source and located in github.

There are also 2 sample apps that show how you can use tableView on your application.